# Multiple Shadow layer android

Tags: java, android

I would like to have 2 shadow layers (upper and bottom shadow)for my text. Currently, it seems that we can only have at most one shadow layer for a TextView. Of course I can do that with 3 TextViews, but it'll be apparently slow and stupid.

Comment: make a custom view then, override `onDraw` and draw whatever you like there

Comment: Can you send me code for this issue...???

Comment: code?  no,  you have to do that on your own